# Inner Query Parse

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mongodb, parse-platform

[image]
Im trying to link a ticket that a user creates that is linked to a recipient but I am not getting anything back, I am able to get the tickets from the tickets table but the matching of the innerquery doesn't seem to link. Going off the parse docs, I tried using an inner query to use as a link or a bridge as follows:

```
let innerQuery = PFQuery(className:"Tickets")
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Messages")

        //get all tickets for current user
        innerQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.objectId as Any)
        //objectId is ticketId in tickets table
        innerQuery.includeKey("objectId")
        //match to ticketId in messages table
        query.whereKey("ticketId", matchesQuery: innerQuery)

        do {
            let returnedObjects = try query.findObjects()
            for object in returnedObjects {
                let sender = object["sender"] as? String
                }
            }
        } catch {

        }
```

Comment: I notice that the column you are using to link the tables is a String and not a Pointer.  Pointers should be used as keys to other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when we need to do Inner query in Parse Server we will save the column as Pointer object. So here you need to save the **ticketId** column in the **Message** table as a Pointer Class of **Tickets** class. You can save it like this:

```
let pointerObj = [“__type": "Pointer", "className": "Tickets", "objectId": "yourClassObjectId"]
messagePraseObj.setValue(pointerObj, forKey: “ticketId")
```

After that, you can use the below code for achieving your task. I used it on my projects. 
I have used iOS SDK version 1.17.3 and swift 4.

```
    let innerQuery = PFQuery.init(className: "Tickets")
    innerQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.objectId as Any)

    let query = PFQuery.init(className: "Messages")
    query.whereKey("ticketId", matchesQuery: innerQuery)
    query.includeKey("ticketId")

    query.findObjectsInBackground { (returnedObjects, error) in
        if error == nil && returnedObjects != nil {
            for object in returnedObjects! {
                let ticket = object.value(forKey: "ticketId") as! PFObject
                let sender = ticket.value(forKey: "user") as? String ?? ""
                print("User ID: \(sender)")
            }
        }
    }
```

For more information: https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#relational-queries

Hope it will help you.

Comment: this was great help, thanks! Now I guess my only other question would be is there an easier way to retrieve on that same 'ticketId' column from the Messages table as a pointer like I was able to do with it being a string value? (ie: query.whereKey("ticketId", equalTo: "ticketId31434") ) because Im not sure how it would effect performance if I would have to double filter on a different query where that column is involved not as an inner query.

Comment: nevermind - figured it out: 
query.whereKey("columnName", equalTo: PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "ClassName", objectId: "objectid2421")) in case anyone stumbles upon this in the future